# Hiding visibility of variables in a c++ source file

Tags: c++, static, extern

I am using cpp file to initialize some data

```
// foo.cpp

#include "foo.h"

int val = 5;
```

& using header to share it with other files in the project.

```
// foo.h

extern int val;

inline int get() {
    return val;
}
```

But I don't want the variable *val* to be accessible in other files of the project. I want to access the value through *get()* function. Is there any way to achieve this?

I've tried another approach...

```
// foo.h

class foo {

private:

    static int val;

public:

    static int get() {
        return val;
    }

    static void set();
}
```

&...

```
// foo.cpp

void foo::set() {
    val = 5;
}
```

but it too doesn't work. Getting linker error: *unresolved external symbol "private: static int foo::val"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in foo.cpp add:-

```
 int foo::val;
```

Comment: Error: 'foo::val' : 'static' storage-class specifier illegal on members.

Comment: @kumarchandresh oops. Yes, you don't need the 'static' in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Put in the .cpp file

```
int foo:val = 5;
```

to give it the space it requires.

Comment: Error: 'foo::val' : 'static' storage-class specifier illegal on members.

Answer (score 1):

You need class member or free variable? If you want free variable, just remove variable declaration from header file, remove definition of `get()` (leave the declaration) and implement `get()` in .cpp file.

Comment: I'd rather have my get() function inline... Please help!